# Move through 2 dimensional array using pointers only

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array

What I want is to go through the array using pointers only:

```cpp
int I[5][5] = { { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50},
                { 11, 21, 31, 41, 51},
                { 12, 22, 32, 42, 52},
                { 13, 23, 33, 43, 53},
                { 14, 24, 34, 44, 54} };
```

So, using a `for` loop, I can print the values of the array using pointers instead of indices, like this:

```cpp
for(int(*p)[5] = I ; p<I+(sizeof(I)/sizeof(I[0])) ; p++){
    for(int* q=*p ; q<*(p+1) ; q++){
        cout<<*q<<" ";
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
```

But, if I want to get access to the next 2 values underneath `*q`, how do I get those? For example, if `*q` equals 10, in the same iteration I want to get 11 and 12 as well. And when `*q` equals 32, I want to get 33 and 34.

I tried creating pointers like these, but I can't figure what else to do:

```cpp
int* p_ini = *(I);
int* p_fin = *(I+4);
int* q_ini = p_ini;
int* q_fin = (p_ini+4);
```

Again, all of this without using any indexes.

Comment: Why do you want to use pointers only?  Doing so seems to constitute an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: If you know the size of the array in advance you can create it in one dimension.You can retain addressing it via indicies via `int data[25]` and `int* I[5] = {data + 0, data + 5, data + 10, ....}`. After that if you have some `int* q = &(I[2][2])` you can `q + 5 == I[3][2]` and `q + 1 == &(I[2][3])`, but it would seem a pain to deal with checking bounds, so possibly not the best solution given what you want

Comment: isn't `*(p+1)` UB when `p` points to the last row?

Answer (score 0):

If you have an `int(*)[5]` pointer to an element of the outer array (`p`), incrementing that pointer by `1` will get you an `int(*)[5]` pointer to the next element in the outer array (`p+1`), by `1` again to get the next element (`p+2`), and so on.

Then, you can dereference each of those pointers to get `int*` pointers to the 1st elements of those inner arrays (`q`, `q2`, `q3`, etc).

Then, you can increment those `int*` pointers by the desired number of elements (which you can easily calculate while iterating the earlier inner array pointed by `p`), ie `*(q2+0)` and `*(q3+0)` when `*q==10`, `*(q2+2)` and `*(q3+2)` when `*q==32`, etc.

For example:

```
for(int(*p)[5] = I; p < I+(sizeof(I)/sizeof(I[0])); ++p){
    for(int *first = *p, *q = first; q < *(p+1); ++q){
        if (*q == 10 || *q == 32) {
            size_t offset = q - first;
            int *q2 = *(p+1) + offset;
            int *q3 = *(p+2) + offset;
            cout << *q << ": " << *q2 << ", " << *q3 << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/bZHXqu)